# iOs setPrimitiveValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

On an `NSManagedObject`, if I invoke `setPrimitiveValue`, does it need to be wrapped in `{will|did}ChangeValueForKey` statements, **if it is used in a non-setting/getter method?**

e.g. I want to have a method that takes a key (NSString) and increments the value of a property on the model object.

```
-(void) incrementItem:(NSString *)key
{
    NSNumber *value = [self primitiveValueForKey:key];
    int intValue = value.intValue;

    [self setPrimitiveValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: intValue++] forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: This will set `key` to the old value and because the increased `intValue` is never read.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your KVO methods when accessing the primitive value (or backing ivar for non-managed objects) should always be done. So, your method should look like:

```
-(void) incrementItem:(NSString *)key
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:key];
    NSNumber *value = [self primitiveValueForKey:key];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:key];
    int intValue = value.intValue;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:key];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: intValue++] forKey:key];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: what about `willAccessValueForKey` around the first `primitiveValueForKey`?

Comment: so you are saying whenever using one of the "primitive" methods, it needs to be wrapped, regardless of whether its in a accessor

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a pain, but it's in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html).

Comment: Core Data on iOS 5+ and OS X 10.7+ will let you use dynamically created, primitive properties like `@property (nonatomic) u_int32_t propertyName;`.

Comment: yes i started with those docs -- i don't see where they say you need to use the methods **even if you are not in an accessor method**.

Comment: You need to, probably, because the value might be a fault. By telling Core Data that you're about to access that value, it can ensure that it's loaded into memory first.